# Storing file in memory ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, memory, temporary-files

Im trying to split a file into chunks and have them added to a list of temp files in ruby, so that i can then traverse the list and upload them to distributed storage.

The problem i seem to be having is that the tempfiles in `@fileList` get garbage collected and the list is filled with closed files.

```
require_relative 'file_uploader'
require 'fileutils'
require 'tempfile'
class FileSplitAlgorytham

  def initialize
    #@uploadFileUs = UploadToUs.new("blogs/1/articles/1/images/10/")
    #@uploadFileIreland = UploadToIreland.new("blogs/1/articles/1/images/10/")
    @chunksize = 1_073
    @fileList = []
  end

  attr_reader :fileList

  def splitFile(file_in)
    @filetype = File.extname(file_in)
    outfilenum = 1
    File.open(file_in,"r") do |fh_in|
      until fh_in.eof?
        Tempfile.open("#{outfilenum}#{@filetype}") do |fh_out|
          line = ""
          while fh_out.size <= (@chunksize -line.length) && !fh_in.eof?
            line = fh_in.readline
            fh_out << line
          end
          #upload files with modulo and counter?
           @fileList << fh_out
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

After this i would like to be able to traverse through `@fileList` and upload them to 2 different cloud storage providers

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks for your time

Comment: do you need to use tempfiles? Seems like you could avoid the gargabe collection issue if you used a hosting platfom that let you create files.

Comment: I thanks for your reply, I am trying to build a distributed file storage solution for my app. I want the files split and then stored (created) on two providers

Comment: This is not an issue with garbage collection. The files are closed because you are using the block form of `.open` - which closes file when block is done. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open

Comment: Thanks @NeilSlater, fileList << File.open(fh_out) fixed my problem. write as an answer and i'll accept it if you like :)